# remove Dynamic Converter js

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

We tried Dynamic Converter for multiple currency function (http://dynamicconverter.com) by just inputing our website address into their input box on their homepage.

We just hope to try their multiple currency function, but since then, we found our website would always has their multiple currencies label under each product, and also we find in the webpage header of our website, there always have following js and css automatically:

```
<script id="dcdlay" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://converter2.dynamicconverter.com/accounts/12/12601.js">
var zpExvF = unescape('{var zJLsfe %3D unescape%28%27%2..};; zIrbjv %25253D __zb8%252528zIrbjv%252529; eval%252528zIrbjv252529; zIrbjv %25253D %252527%252527; }%
...."});}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.DynamicConverter_float_div { background-color: #F9F9F9; border:1px solid #ababab; text-align: center; z-index:999; } 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar { background-color: #506DC7; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; padding: 2px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; } 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar a, 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar a:link, 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar a:visited, 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar a:active, 
.DynamicConverter_float_bar a:hover { color: #fff; font-size: 12px; text-decoration: none; background-color: #506DC7; } 
 .DynamicConverter_float_text { color: #000; font-weight:normal; font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
```

We just wonder how they insert these js/css into the page header?

Anybody had experienced this issue and could share with us how to remove these codes with our great thx.

Comment: from their website it notes you have to add a code of theirs to your site. Their code is likely appending this code. You should remove that from the source of your webpage. If that is not the problem, can you post the source of your webpage please?

Comment: no, they haven't any notes. we just input our address on their website.

Comment: it looks like the code has been inserted only when running. and the js link as : <script id="dcdlay" type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://converter2.dynamicconverter.com/accounts/12/12601.js">, and they create one account on their site for us, and whenever we access our site, it would alwyas automatically go to their site firstly, so as they can insert their js into the header. But how they could direct us to their site firstly? would they have some plugin on my personal computer, or not?

Comment: They can't direct to their site, but when you include a .js file from their site they can use that to insert whatever they want into your page. If you don't like what they are doing you should contact them to sort out the issue.

Comment: we haven't include any .js file into our webpage, and that's why we don't know how these included js and css coming into our webpage. we have to contact Dynamic Converter for their help.

Comment: The only way it can work on your site is if you added that line of code. If no one did, then check from another computer to see if it is only there for you. Maybe they added an extension to your browser???